# Why does my program skip nextDouble() after the exception is caught?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to figure out why my program is skipping a user input so I can come up with a solution. If I intentionally give it bad input and cause the InputMismatchException to be thrown, it skips the `inputDouble = in.nextDouble();` line. Here is what the output looks like:

```
Please enter floating point value or -1 to stop
15.7
Please enter floating point value or -1 to stop
15.7
Please enter floating point value or -1 to stop
r
Number format is incorrect please try again
Please enter floating point value or -1 to stop
Number format is incorrect please try again
Total is: 31.4
```

And here is my code

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddingNumbers {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double inputDouble = 0;
        double total = 0;
        int tries = 0;
        boolean done = false;

        while (!done) {
            if (tries < 2) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Please enter floating point value or -1 to stop");
                    inputDouble = in.nextDouble();

                    if (inputDouble != -1) {
                        total = total + inputDouble;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Total is: " + total);
                        done = true;
                    }
                } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
                    System.out.println("Number format is incorrect please try again");
                    tries++;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Total is: " + total);
                done = true;
            }
        }

        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What environment?  Is this inside an IDE like NetBeans or Eclipse?  Some IDEs have odd buffering issues that make it look like your program is reading a line behind.  Please let us know *exactly* where and how you're doing this input typing.

Comment: Sorry it's Eclipse. Changing it to inputFloat = new Scanner(System.in).nextFloat(); fixed it however now I have an error for a resource leak. Is there another way to close it besides in.close() ?

Comment: I edited my answer to add some additional information. If it helped solve your problem consider selecting it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put a blank `in.nextLine();` right below your `inputDouble=in.nextDouble();`

Comment: No luck I got the same result:                                                                    Please enter floating point value or -1 to stop
15.7
Please enter floating point value or -1 to stop
15.7
Please enter floating point value or -1 to stop
15.7
Please enter floating point value or -1 to stop
r
Number format is incorrect please try again
Please enter floating point value or -1 to stop
Number format is incorrect please try again
Total is: 47.09999942779541

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner still has invalid input in the buffer. To "clear" the buffer you need to use `in.nextLine();`. Use `in.nextLine();` after `tries++` to solve your problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @silwar Explain to me how is this not the answer. I ran the code and it checks out.

Comment: @Alexander A bit more of an explanation as to *why* this is the right answer would be helpful. As-is, it just looks like a "try this".

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Although I also wouldn't hate to know WHY it worked :-)

Comment: @GarrettPenfield Updated answer.